# Integer.parseInt format exception

Tags: java, numberformatexception, parseint

I have a problem passing a string to int with Integer.parseInt function. 
The string you want to spend a webService downloaded in the DB has as varchar (1) format (not sure if this is important).

My code is very simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i <todo.size (); i ++) 
{
numT = Integer.parseInt (todo.get (i) .getRespT ()); 
numV = Integer.parseInt (todo.get (i) .getRespV ()); 
         ... 
}
```

And this is what it tells me the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.opofire/app.opofire.Soluciones}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1"
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
at app.opofire.Soluciones.corregirTest(Soluciones.java:157)
at app.opofire.Soluciones.onCreate(Soluciones.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
... 11 more
```

I have tried to show with Log.i the value of the string if it had gotten a blank, I've seen some other post on the forum, but it shows me a 1 only

Thank you very much.

PD: i've put this for debugging:

```
Log.i("",""+todo.get(i).getRespV().length());
```

and it shows that the length is 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string probably has leading spaces. Try trimming it before converting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < todo.size(); i++)
{
    numT = Integer.parseInt (todo.get(i).getRespT().trim());
    numV = Integer.parseInt (todo.get(i).getRespV().trim());
         ...
}
```